# Http request between two containers

Tags: django, reactjs, amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose

I am creating a web service which uses react for the frontend and django REST for the backend. Both are running in separate docker containers. My docker-compose file looks like this.

```
services: 
 db:
  image: postgres
  volumes:
    - ./config/load.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
  environment:
    - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
    - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
    - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
web:
  build: .
  image: gudmundurorri4/hoss-web
  command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
  volumes:
    - .:/code
  stdin_open: true
  ports:
    - "8000:8000"
  depends_on:
    - db
frontend:
  image: gudmundurorri4/hoss-frontend
  stdin_open: true
  ports:
    - "3000:3000"
  depends_on:
    - "web"
```

Both the web and frontend containers work fine. The backend works when I open it in the browser and when I execute a get request to http://web:8000 from within the frontend container I get the correct response. However when I execute a GET request from my react app using the same address (http://web:8000) it always fails with the error

net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Comment: Where is your React app running?

Answer (score 1):

The Compose service names only are a thing within the containers themselves (set up using local DNS magic).

From the viewpoint of your (or a user's) browser, there's no such thing as `http://web:8000`.

You'll have to either

- publish the backend with a port and DNS name that's accessible to your users, e.g. `https://backend.myservice.kittens/` and have the frontend that runs in your browser request things from there (be mindful of CORS).
- or have the frontend service proxy those requests through to the backend (that *it* can access via `http://web:8000/`). If you're using webpack-dev-server, it has this capability built-in.